# ¿Cómo extraer con pregmatch() con saltos de linea?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Hola tengo el siguiente extracción de texto pero no logro extraer el texto de abajo, solo me extrae vacio o el * alguna forma de capturarlo?

```
*NOMBRE*\r\n
  Javiera\r\n
*FUENTE*\r\n
  PAGINA WEB\r\n
```

Probe con esto `preg_match('/FUENTE\s*(.*)/', $oMe, $source_2);`

Me retorna eso

```
array:2 [
  0 => "FUENTE*\r"
  1 => "*\r"
]
```

¿Alguna forma de capturar el texto debajo del text FUENTE O NOMBRE?

Comment: Puedes visualizar en el array \r\n ?

Comment: @Jorgesys En el primero hize un dd($variable) y me los visualiza los \r\n, luego hize otro dd($source_2) para ver lo que me retorna el resultado del preg_match y en el array solo me esta retornando la \r pero me retorna vacio

array:2 [
  0 => "FUENTE*\r"
  1 => ""
]

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/FUENTE\s\*\r\n(.*)/', $oMe, $source_2);
```

Es preciso *consumir* `\n` explícitamente, porque `.` no coincide con `\n`.